# python function not repeating

Tags: python, function

I have a python tool to 'touch' (utime) a file, then move to another folder. However, if the file already exists in the destination folder, it is silently overwritten. I would like to check for a file of the same name in the destination folder and, if it exists, rename the one I am moving to its name plus '-*n*' at the end, where *n* is a number starting at '1' and, if the file with '-1' at the end already exists, '-2' etc.
For example, say in the source folder is a file 'foo.txt', but there is one 'foo.txt' in the destination folder as well. This function should return '(absolute path)/foo**-1**.txt'.

So, I have made a function to check for these circumstances and return the modified string, so I can use rename later and not overwrite. However, currently, if the file exists, it returns nothing. Following is the function code, assuming these vars:

*fileName* - input filepath, absolute path. e.g. /Users/foo/sourceFolder/bar.txt
*index* - iterator variable, set to '1' at the start of each file being opened (externally to function)

```
def checkExists(fileName):
    global index
    print "checkExists(" + fileName + ")"

    if exists(fileName):
        splitPath = split(newFile)
        splitName = splitext(splitPath[1])
        newSplitName = splitName[0] + "-" + str(index)

        index += 1
        newName = splitPath[0] + "/" + newSplitName + splitName[1]

        print "newName = " + newName
    else:
        print "(else) fileName = " + fileName
        print "(else) fileName = " + str(type(fileName))
        print ""
        return fileName

    checkExists(newName)
```

Now it seems that the inner call for *checkExists()* at the end is not running.

I hope I have been clear in my explanation.
**IAmThePiGuy**

P.S. I do not want to hear about potential race problems with utime, I know that the files in the source directory will not be accessed by anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that, if the file exists, you don't return anything. I think you're intending to use recursion to check the new filename, but you don't return the result of that call. Here's a stab:

```
def checkExists(fileName, index=0):
    print "checkExists(" + fileName + ")"

    if exists(fileName):
        splitPath = split(newFile)
        splitName = splitext(splitPath[1])
        newSplitName = splitName[0] + "-" + str(index)

        index += 1
        newName = splitPath[0] + "/" + newSplitName + splitName[1]

        print "newName = " + newName
        return checkExists(newName, index)   # recurse
    else:
        print "(else) fileName = " + fileName
        print "(else) fileName = " + str(type(fileName))
        print ""
        return fileName
```

I also took the liberty of moving the recursive call closer to the generation of `newName` and removing the global variable and replacing that with recursion as well.

Comment: thanks, that's just what I was looking for, I didn't realise that if I told it to return itself it would recurse!

Comment: Well, it'll recurse in any case, it just won't return the result of the recursion to the original caller. An iterative solution will technically run faster, but in your use case I doubt you'll notice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an iterative approach to a similar problem:

```
def copyfile(path, dstdir, verbose=True, dryrun=False):
    """Copy `path` file to `dstdir` directory incrementing name if necessary."""
    filename = os.path.basename(path)
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)

    for i in itertools.count(2):
        destpath = os.path.join(dstdir, filename)
        if not os.path.exists(destpath):
            if verbose:
                print(path, '->', destpath)
            if not dryrun:
                shutil.copyfile(path, destpath)
            return
        # increment filename
        filename = "%s_%02d%s" % (basename, i, ext)
```

Comment: that looks like a good answer, but it's way above my current prowess in python :-)